# Is there any jQuery method like do method as in my example?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that i can simply write a plugin for it and i know that i can do this manually. I am just looking simple way if jQuery provide such as option.

Actualy each method will work as expected but it does not make feel it is effective way because it is clear that there is no iteration. There is only one element.
Check example below.

```
$('a').first().do(function(element){
  //do your job
}).end().eq(2).do(function(element){
  // do another job
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jQuery each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
$('a').first().each(function(element){
  $(this).html("foo");
}).end().eq(2).each(function(element){
  $(this).html("bar");
});
```

Comment: I think there is no another better option

Answer (score 0):

`each` would work instead of `do`, even though you are only dealing with one item.